# urlSession:dataTask:didReceive:completionHandler not called in Xcode8 Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I've created a background `URLSession` object using the following code:

```
let identifier = /* some background identifier */
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: identifier)
self.session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
```

I've also implemented the following `URLSessionDataDelegate` methods in the delegate class:

```
public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive response: URLResponse, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
    // code goes here
}

public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
    // code goes here
}

public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) { 
    // code goes here
}
```

I'm able to successfully call `URLSessionUploadTask` from this session using the following:

```
let fileURl = /* some file url */
let request = /* some URLRequest */
let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, fromFile: fileUrl)
task.resume()
```

But for some reason I only get callbacks for:

```
`urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)`
```

and

```
`urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data)`.
```

The delegate method:

```
`urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive response: URLResponse, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void)`
```

never gets called.

Is this a bug in Xcode8 or am I missing something important?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is it a working code and works fine in earlier xcode ?

Comment: The code works as I am getting delegate callbacks on the other two delegate methods, I cannot test this in earlier Xcode because they don't support Swift 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct quote from Apple SDK regarding this method:

```
/*
 * Messages related to the operation of a task that delivers data
 * directly to the delegate.
 */
@protocol NSURLSessionDataDelegate <NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>
@optional
/* The task has received a response and no further messages will be
 * received until the completion block is called. The disposition
 * allows you to cancel a request or to turn a data task into a
 * download task. This delegate message is optional - if you do not
 * implement it, you can get the response as a property of the task.
 *
 * This method will not be called for background upload tasks (which cannot be converted to download tasks).
 */
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
                                 didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
                                  completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition disposition))completionHandler;
```

Edit: added more context to a quote

Comment: Can you provide a link to this direct quote?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Interesting that this information only shows on Obj-C documentation and not in the Swift documentation. I'll flag that with apple. Thanks a lot, anonymous one!